# How to determine prime number

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

I'm trying to write a program using the OCaml language, but am experiencing problems utilizing nested functions. Here's the code I wrote:

```
let prime : int -> bool
= fun x ->
  if x > 2 then
    let a = x - 1 in
      let rec checkZero a x =
        if a > 1 then
          match x mod a with
           0 -> false
          |_ -> checkZero (a - 1) x
        else if a = 1 then
          true
  else if x = 2 then
    true
  else
    false
;;
```

To briefly explain my code, I'm using a nested function called `checkZero` to determine whether or not `x` is divisible by a value `a` which starts at `x - 1` and goes down until 2.

After performing pattern matching, if the result of the `mod` operation is 0, then `x` is not a prime number, and if the result is anything else then we subtract 1 from `a` and perform `checkZero` again.

The particular error message that I'm getting is that I'm getting a syntax error where the double semicolons are.

I'm not too familiar with how OCaml works, but I do know that double semicolons are used when you want the entire code to be an expression.
I'm not entirely sure what is causing the error, though.

Comment: There might be more errors here, but you're never actually using the function other than recursively inside the function itself. `let` is also not an expression in itself, which is likely where the syntax error comes from. You need to use `let ... in` followed by an expression that invokes it.

Comment: Hi, thank you @glennsl for the feedback. Your last suggestion helped me figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that problem and feel rather silly now that I've seen it. I hope it helps anybody else struggling with similar issues.

As @glennsl has stated in the comment on the question, one thing I was missing is that "`let ... in` must be followed by an expression that invokes it." The problem with my code is that the `checkZero` function was not performing as I intended due to the lack of invocation.

Another thing that I realized is that rather than using `if ... then ... else ...` statements, it's more convenient to perform pattern matching at times.

Here's the code I came up with that works (if there are any errors in the code, please feel free to let me know):

```
let prime : int -> bool
= fun x ->
  match x with
     0 -> false
   | 1 -> false
   | _ -> let a = (x - 1) in
            let rec checkZero a x =
              if (a > 1) then
                match x mod a with
                   0 -> false
                 | _ -> checkZero (a - 1) x
              else
                true
              in
              checkZero a x
;;
```

An equivalent version without using the conditional statements is:

```
let prime : int -> bool
= fun n ->
  match n with
     0 -> false
   | 1 -> false
   | _ -> let a = (n - 1) in
            let rec checkZero a n =
              match a with
                 1 -> true
               | _ -> match n mod a with
                         0 -> false
                       | _ -> checkZero (a - 1) n
              in
              checkZero a n
;;
```

Comment: Why a nested function if you don't take advantage of it? n is bound outside the nested function and doesn't need to be an argument. Also combine the fun and match into `function 0 -> false | 1 -> false | n -> ...`.

Comment: Algorithmically you can do a lot better too. Start by checking for 2 and divisible by two. From then on you only need to check divisibility by odd numbers. You can also start `a` at 3 and count it up till `a * a > n`. That means you only need to check a fraction of the numbers compared to your current code.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, here's a simpler function that operates in the same way as yours (with no optimisations but shorter) :

```ml
let prime n =
    let rec checkZero x d = match d with
        | 1 -> true    
        | _ -> (x mod d <> 0) && checkZero x (d-1)
    in match n with
    | 0 | 1 -> false
    | _ -> checkZero n (n-1) ;;
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed code samples here are all far too verbose compared to the true conciseness one should be able to achieve with OCaml. Here is what it should look like.

Naive implementation:

```
let is_prime num =
  let rec prime_num num next = 
    next <= 1 ||  ((num mod next) <> 0) && prime_num num (next-1)
  in
  prime_num num (num-1);;
```

Optimized version:

```
let isPrime n =
  (* Returns true if n has no divisors between m and sqrt(n) inclusive. *)
  let rec noDivisors m =
    m * m > n || (n mod m != 0 && noDivisors (m + 1))
  in
  n >= 2 && noDivisors 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer an implementation such that you do not test all the previous numbers as potential divisors, but you only test the prime smaller than the integer to be tested.

This code should do this job:

```
(* helper to pront a list *)
let print_list lst =
  print_string (String.concat " " (List.map string_of_int lst));;

(* main function, starts at n>2 *)
let primes_lower_than n =
  let list_of_primes = ref [2]
  in 
  for k = 3 to n do
    (* I hope that List.for_all stop to test as soon as there is a False *)
    let not_divided_by i =
      (k mod i) <> 0
    in
    (* Only test if I am a multiple of prime smaller than me *)
    let is_prime = List.for_all not_divided_by !list_of_primes
    in
    if is_prime then 
      (* add smaller integers that are prime to the list *)
      list_of_primes := !list_of_primes @ [k] 
  done ;
  !list_of_primes;;
  

(* Let's try on a given number *)
let num = 47 in
let list_primes = primes_lower_than num
in
(* of course the true test is if the last element of the list is num *)
print_list list_primes
```